# Runtimeerror (python 3.5 or later is required) when I try to install any library

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pyautogui

I am trying to install some libraries to use on my python 3.4, but every time that I run pip install ("name of library") , it returns the following error:

```
Collecting pyautogui
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/35/71/a7d328fe19667777fb0c371ca346c89d1b380f7778fa1ba65aca1090478c/PyAutoGUI-0.9.49.tar.gz
  Exception:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 232, in main
      status = self.run(options, args)
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 339, in run
      requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 385, in prepare_files
      req_to_install.run_egg_info()
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 310, in run_egg_info
      self.setup_py, self.name,
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 281, in setup_py
      import setuptools  # noqa
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
      import setuptools.version
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\version.py", line 1, in <module>
      import pkg_resources
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 93, in <module>
      raise RuntimeError("Python 3.5 or later is required")
  RuntimeError: Python 3.5 or later is required
```

Comment: You seem to have Python 3.4 installed. Update  it to 3.5 and try again.

Comment: `setuptools` dropped support for Python 3.4 as it is EOL. Either downgrade `setuptools` or use a more recent Python version.

Comment: Please how do I downgrade the setup tools

Comment: Try `python -m pip install --upgrade "setuptools<44"`.

Comment: I have the same problem and I tried this command, but it throws the same error when it tries to downgrade.

Comment: @KayceeUde Did you ever solve this problem, and if so how? I am stuck with the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing this because pip 19.2 has [dropped support for Python 3.4](https://discuss.python.org/t/pip-19-2-is-now-available/2022).

Good news: The `get-pip.py` script has been [updated](https://discuss.python.org/t/when-will-setuptools-and-wheel-drop-support-for-python-3-4/2126) to include a 3.4-specific option. You can use the following command to request pip 19.1, the last version of pip that supports Python 3.4:

```
python get-pip.py pip==19.1
```

Comment: I tried this command but it throws the same error when it tries to run get-pip.py

Answer (score 0):

The best option here is (if you can) to upgrade to a supported python version, see https://endoflife.date/python for the list of the currently supported python versions